# C++ use keybd_event a random number of times

Tags: c++, windows

I want that my program executes the keybd_event a random number of times per Loop

```
if (KeyDown(0x46))

     {
          srand(time(NULL));

          keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0x28,(rand() % 1) ,rand() % 1);
          Sleep(rand() % 801 + 5);
          keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0x28, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
          Sleep(rand() % 101);
          keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0x27, (rand() % 1), rand() % 1);
          Sleep(rand() % 801 + 5);
          keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0x27, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
          Sleep(rand() % 101);
          keybd_event(VK_UP, 0x26, (rand() % 1), rand() % 1);
          Sleep(rand() % 801 + 5);
          keybd_event(VK_UP, 0x26, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
          Sleep(rand() % 101);
          keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0x25, rand() % 1, rand() % 1);
          Sleep(rand() % 801 + 5);
          keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0x25, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
          Sleep(rand() % 101);
```

for example I want when I press F that it presses the Up,down,left,right arrow keys randomly between 1 - 10 times. I want a rand() % 10 func in front of the keybd_event. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear for me. As far as I understood you want to press 'F' key and randomly choose a key among [LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, DOWN] and emulate it 1 to 10 times? If this is the case then the code should look something like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));

DWORD dwKeys[] = { VK_DOWN, VK_RIGHT, VK_LEFT, VK_TOP };
const DWORD key = rand() % _countof(dwKeys); // Randomly select a key
int times = rand() % 10;
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
{
    EmulateKeyPress(key);
}
```